# How do I call a service from my controller in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, services

I'm writing a plugin, and used plugin.io to generate my scaffolding.  In my controller I am attempting to call a service, and getting an error.

This is my service code from my generated plugin it lives at `fulcrumdonation/services/FulcrumDonation_FulcrumCyberSourceService.php`:

```
class FulcrumDonation_FulcrumCyberSourceService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
    /**
     *
     * From any other plugin file, call it like this:
     *
     *     craft()->fulcrumDonation_FulcrumCyberSource->exampleService()
     */
    public function exampleService()
    {
    }
}
```

And just as the scaffolding suggests, I'm attempting to call this function in the controller:

```
craft()->fulcrumDonation_FulcrumCyberSource->exampleService();
```

But when I add that line of code in the controller I get the following error:

> Property "Craft\WebApp.fulcrumDonation_FulcrumCyberSource" is not
>   defined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like there's a mistake in my generator. Lo ciento, I will fix it

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  And also, thank you @khalwat for your generator.  You saved me a lot of work and research when beginning my first plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with a lowercase `f` in the middle...

```
craft()->fulcrumDonation_fulcrumCyberSource->exampleService();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The plugin comment generator had it wrong!

Comment: I've since fixed this on https://pluginfactory.io